# Invert a list into a data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a `list`:

```
ll <- list(A=c("p1","p2"),B=c("p1","p4"),C=c("p3","p6"))
```

And I'm looking for a `function` that will convert it into a `data.frame` such that one column (`a` below) holds the unique elements of the `unlisted` `ll`, and the other (`b` below) holds the names of list elements to which the unlisted elements correspond to in `ll`.

The resulting `data.frame` for this example would therefore be:

```
data.frame(a = c("p1","p1","p2","p3","p4","p6"),
           b = c("A","B","A","C","B","C"))
```

Comment: You need `stack(ll)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun